# Cómo corregir este problema al iniciar sesión?

Tags: php

Al ingresar este código que he estado viendo y acoplando de internet me sale un error en la línea 26 del archivo "login.php", he seguido el codigo al pie de la letra y no se por qué no funciona o que fallas tiene a la hora de iniciar sesión

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['nombredelusuario']))
{
    header ('location: pgina.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btningresar'])){

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="prueba";

$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(!$conn)
{
    die ("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre=$_POST['txtusuario'];
$pass=$_POST['txtpassword'];

$query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE ususario = ' " .$nombre. " ' and password = ' " .$pass. " '");
$nr=mysqli_num_rows($query);

if(!isset($_SESSION['nombredelusuario'])){

if($nr == 1){
    $_SESSION['nombredelusuario']=$nombre;
    header("location: pagina.php");
}

elseif ($nr == 0) {
    echo "<script>alter('Usuario no existe');window.location= 'index.php' </script>";
}



}

}

?>
```

La línea 26 en cuestión es la de $nr(mysqli_num_rows)

Comment: en la linea 25 esta ususario en vez de "usuario", seguro tu campo se llama "ususario" ?

Comment: Ya le cambié el campo pero aún así me sale el mismo error

Comment: haz echo de la sentencia sql antes de ejecutarla

Comment: @JuanEsteban Comentanos que error te sigue saliendo porfavor

Answer (score 1):

El error puede ser provocado por la consulta:

> "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = ' " .$nombre. " ' and password =
> ' " .$pass. " '"

Si tienes espacios, aunque escribas correctamente el usuario y password  estos no se podrán encontrar al realizar la consulta.

Debes evitar los espacios en blanco, revisa la posición del contenedor de caracteres ( `'` ):

> "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = '" .$nombre. "' and password = '"
> .$pass. "'"